# Python - Get specific lines from file

Tags: python

How can I get specific lines from a file in Python? I know how to read files and get it in a list etc, but this is a bit harder for me. Let me explain what I need:

I have a file that looks like this:

> lcl|AF033819.3_cds_AAC82593.1_1 [gene=gag] [protein=Gag] [protein_id=AAC82593.1] [location=336..1838]
>   ATGGGTGCGAGAGCGTCAGTATTAAGCGGGGGAGAATTAGATCGATGGGAAAAAATTCGGTTAAGGCCAG
>   GGGGAAAGAAAAAATATAAATTAAAACATATAGTATGGGCAAGCAGGGAGCTAGAACGATTCGCAGTTAA
>   TCACTCTTTGGCAACGACCCCTCGTCACAATAA
>   lcl|AF033819.3_cds_AAC82598.2_2 [gene=pol] [protein=Pol] [partial=5'] [protein_id=AAC82598.2] [location=<1631..4642]
>   TTTTTTAGGGAAGATCTGGCCTTCCTACAAGGGAAGGCCAGGGAATTTTCTTCAGAGCAGACCAGAGCCA
>   ACAGCCCCACCAGAAGAGAGCTTCAGGTCTGGGGTAGAGACAACAACTCCCCCTCAGAAGCAGGAGCCGA
>   lcl|AF033819.3_cds_AAC82594.1_3 [gene=vif] [protein=Vif] [protein_id=AAC82594.1] [location=4587..5165]
>   ATGGAAAACAGATGGCAGGTGATGATTGTGTGGCAAGTAGACAGGATGAGGATTAGAACATGGAAAAGTT
>   TAGTAAAACACCATATGTATGTTTCAGGGAAAGCTAGGGGATGGTTTTATAGACATCACTATGAAAGCCC

I need to remove every line that contains:

> lcl|AF033819.3_cds_AAC82594.1_3 [gene=vif] [protein=Vif] [protein_id=AAC82594.1] [location=4587..5165]

All the letters I need to store in a list, file, etc. I know how that works. Can anyone help me with the code in Python? How do I only delete lines that contain:

> lcl

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is it about that line that flags it for removal?  Also you do not explain what format the output should be. You say you know how to read files, you should edit the question to include the code you have so far.

Comment: Also, can you please re-post that data in a code block so that we can see what the lines actually look like?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html). It will be something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'beginlcl|AF033819.3_cds_AAC82593.1_1 [gene=gag] [protein=Gag] [protein_id=AAC82593.1] [location=336..1838]end'
>>> re.sub('lcl.*?location.*?\]', '', a)
'beginend'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `startswith()`?

```
with open('lcl.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith("lcl|"):
            print ("lcl line dropping it")
            continue
        else:
            print (line)
```

Result:

```
lcl line dropping it
ATGGGTGCGAGAGCGTCAGTATTAAGCGGGGGAGAATTAGATCGATGGGAAAAAATTCGGTTAAGGCCAG GGGGAAAGAAAAAATATAAATTAAAACATATAGTATGGGCAAGCAGGGAGCTAGAACGATTCGCAGTTAATCACTCTTTGGCAACGACCCCTCGTCACAATAA

lcl line dropping it
TTTTTTAGGGAAGATCTGGCCTTCCTACAAGGGAAGGCCAGGGAATTTTCTTCAGAGCAGACCAGAGCCA ACAGCCCCACCAGAAGAGAGCTTCAGGTCTGGGGTAGAGACAACAACTCCCCCTCAGAAGCAGGAGCCGA

lcl line dropping it
ATGGAAAACAGATGGCAGGTGATGATTGTGTGGCAAGTAGACAGGATGAGGATTAGAACATGGAAAAGTT TAGTAAAACACCATATGTATGTTTCAGGGAAAGCTAGGGGATGGTTTTATAGACATCACTATGAAAGCCC
```

Note: I am assuming that there are newlines in the right places here!